# Scrambling(randomize) row id's in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table `images` with ID's starting from 1 to 5000. On the page they are showed straight from 1 to 5000. What I wonder is it possible to scramble the records inside database table not to query them by `RAND()` on the page because they will be random on every refresh. I don't want this.

For example `id(1) to become id(343)`.. `id(453)->id(4444)` and so on.. just scrambling them.

UPDATE:
This is the query which I'm trying

```
alter table images add column randorder double;

update table images
    set randorder = rand();

create index idx_table_randorder on table(randorder);
```

When is executed I got column `randorder` with `NULL` but the query return again

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table images        set randorder = rand()' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
alter table add column randorder double;

update table
    set randorder = rand();

create index idx_table_randorder on table(randorder);
```

Then you can "shuffle" the records by doing:

```
select t.*
from table t
order by randorder;
```

This will use the index so it will be fast.  It is stable, so it will work by paging.  When you want to change the ordering, you can use the `update`.

Comment: Thank's for the answer. Let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

Save the rows into an array. Then run:

```
shuffle($array);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Comment: Doesn't this some kind of `RAND()`? will show again scrambled results on the page on every page refresh... which I try to avoid.

Comment: So, you want to actually scramble the database rows? Or do you want to save the scrambled version? @Stan

Comment: I want scramble the database rows.